# How to change language in DevEcoStudio IDE to english?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, harmonyos, deveco-studio

How to change the IDE language from Chinese to English in DevEcoStudio IDE?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Please go to the Settings/Preferences -> Plugins

Look for this plugin in that list:

**Chinese(Simplified)**

[image]

Uncheck the plugin and restart .Your language will change to English(default).